# HStore field insert issue

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-hstore

I am trying to insert a dictionary into the htore from my python shell and I keep getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function hstore(text[], integer[]) does not exist
LINE 1: ...ula" = hstore(ARRAY['function', 'formula'], ARRAY[hstore(ARR...
                                                         ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The queryset I am using is this:

```
Formula.objects.get_or_create(formula={ 'function': { 'round': 0}, 'formula': {'a':  0.2 , 'b': 5, 'c': 4, 'd': 4, 'e': 1}})
```

Also, I have created the hstore extension and added the app django_hstore. The migration was also successful. I don't understand why it keeps failing.

Comment: what happens if you avoid using get_or_create but use the model save method?

Answer (score 4):

Django's HStoreField accepts only string values, hence the error: `function hstore(text[], integer[]) does not exist`.

Try `{ 'round': '0'}` instead of `{ 'round': 0}` from your example.

Comment: On Django [HStoreField docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield) says `A field for storing mappings of strings to strings.`